# Select 2 records which were grouped, Then put them in 2 columns along side

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, pivot

In a table we have schools' data:

```
 ID | Name | City
------------------  
  1    A     X          
  2    B     X    
  3    C     Z
  4    D     Z
```

I want to have a list of each two schools that are in the same city:

```
Name1 | Name2
--------------  
  A      B          
  C      D
```

I chose schools in the same city with this:

```
 SELECT Name FROM Schools
    Group by City
    Having City = City
```

Is it correct? How to bring 2 matched schools on a new table along side?

Thanks

Comment: Can there be more than two schools per city? If yes, what should the result be?

Comment: What RDBMS (MySql, SQL Server, Oracle, ...) are you using?

Comment: @Leigh Yes. I Like to know how it would be too. in this case with multi column as many as the same cities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** Another way to do it

One way to do that if you insist on grouping

```
SELECT City,
       MIN(Name) Name1,
       MAX(Name) Name2
  FROM Schools
 GROUP BY City
-- HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Another way

```
SELECT City,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 1 THEN Name END) Name1,
       MIN(CASE WHEN rnum = 2 THEN Name END) Name2
  FROM
(
  SELECT s.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY City ORDER BY Name) rnum
    FROM Schools s
) q
 GROUP BY City
```

Sample output:

```
| CITY | NAME1 | NAME2 |
------------------------
|    X |     A |     B |
|    Z |     C |     D |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/071a7d/1)** demo

Comment: What do these `MIN` and `MAX` do here exactly?

Comment: They grab two values per group. One has minimum value in a group and the other maximum.

Comment: What about middle values? Is this because we want just a pair of results? If yes is it the only way?

Comment: What about them? In your question you said you need **two** matched schools. See updated answer for another way to do the same thing.

Comment: Thank You. `--HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` in first method is now useless?

Comment: You're very welcome :) The problem with the first method is that you'll get `Name1` and `Name2` the same if you have only one Name per City. `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` filters out rows that have only one Name per City. So it's up to you to decide whether it useful or not since there isn't enough information in your question about a context in which you want to use this query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Name
FROM Schools a JOIN Schools b ON a.City = b.City 
          AND a.ID != b.ID 
          AND a.Name < b.Name;
```

This returns all the pairs of schools in the same city, not only a pair for each city.

Answer (score 0):

If a city contains more than 2 schools then the following query gives no guarantees as to which 2 schools will be returned:

```
SELECT      S1.Name,
            S2.Name
FROM        (
                SELECT      MIN(ID) ID,
                            City
                FROM        @Schools
                GROUP BY    City
            ) S
INNER JOIN  @Schools S1 ON S.ID = S1.ID
INNER JOIN  @Schools S2 ON ( S.City = S2.City AND S.ID != S2.ID )
```